# Increasing understanding of evaluation/execution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For the following JavaScript code how would one work out the evaluation/execution order? Excluding [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), and focusing on the function `squareList` can one apply the principles of "Right to left" and "inside out" to the code?

What I mean by that is the first statement evaluated by JS in this case would be:

```
return num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0;
```

One this has been evaluated for each item in the array, we will then progress to the line

```
return arr.filter(function (num) {
```

And finally:

```
return Math.pow(num, 2);
```

If I am thinking about this in the wrong way then I need some help please, how can I use a guide or official resouce to know the evaluation/execution order and what will be run first? and the statements following on from that in what order?

entire code block:

```
const squareList = function squareList(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function (num) {
    return num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0;
  }).map(function (num) {
    return Math.pow(num, 2);
  });
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList([-3, 4.8, 5, 3, -3.2]);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: Getting familiar with [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) helps. Outside of the operators and operands, JS statements are executed in the order they appear in the file, except functions, which are executed when invoked.

Comment: The order happens in the same order in which the functions are chained, first the `filter` (evaluating the conditional statement) for each item in the array, returning a new array, then the `map` (evaluating the `Math.pow`) for each item in the array, returning a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const squareList = function squareList(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function (num) {
    return num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0;
  }).map(function (num) {
    return Math.pow(num, 2);
  });
};
```

So the first thing that happens is of course

```
arr.filter(function (num) {
    return num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0;
  })
```

Where the internal function is ran on every element in the array, and for every element that that function returns `true`, the element is added into a resulting filtered array, and that filtered array then takes the place of the entire `arr.filter(...)` block of code

And then you've got

```
filteredArray.map(function (num) {
  return Math.pow(num, 2);
});
```

Where again, the internal function runs on every element, and the return value of that function is added to the NEXT final result array, a mapped array

And then finally you return it

```
return mappedArray
```